# How do I add two view types in a Recycler adapter? I want to make a Android Chatting App

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, chat, adapter

- I'm using retrofit for data fetching
- How do use different xml for both of sender and receiver.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26245139/115145

Comment: create two rows . eg . right.xml left.xml inflate them according to receiver or sender

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `getItemViewType()` of the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Return different values for different views in that callback. You will receive that value in `viewType` of `onCreateViewHolder` callback. Inflate different layouts based on the `viewType`.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 views LEFT and RIGHT based on message type(Send or Received) Visible/Invisible LEFT/RIGHT view